# Jenkins won't start up: "Update required: SSH server"

Tags: jenkins, debian

I have Jenkins installed on a Debian 9 from apt repo. After update (from Repo) to version 2.168, Jenkins won't start up any more. The log contains multiple errors related to many plugins - but it's exactly the same error for all of them:

```
- Failed to load: REST API for Blue Ocean (blueocean-rest 1.25.2)
- Update required: SSH server (sshd 3.1.0) to be updated to 3.236.ved5e1b_cb_50b_2 or higher
```

I have SSH server installed on the system, but it's version `1:7.4p1-10+deb9u7` - nothing like 3.1.0.

What can I do to get Jenkins to start up again?

Comment: Not sure if it will work, but you can try downloading the .hpi file of the plugin and placing it in <JENKINS_HOME>/plugins directory.

Comment: @ycr Your comment lead me to the resolution.  Post it as an answer - and I'll accept

Answer (score 2):

You can try installing the Plugin manually. For this, you have to download the `.hbi` file of the plugin and place it in `<JENKINS_HOME>/plugins` directory before starting the server.

Comment: Took me a bit of time to track down the newer version of jenkins sshd plugin.  After that I move out of $JENKINS_HOME/plugins directory file `sshd.hpi` and directory `sshd` and placed the newly downloaded sshd.hpi there - after this, jenkins started.